# Правила переноса интернет-адресов

Tags: орфография

В газете, где я работаю, часто в рекламных объявлениях приходится давать, помимо всей прочей контактной информации, электронные адреса рекламодателей и адреса их сайтов. Но проблема в том, что газетная колонка имеет ширину всего 4,5 см, а адрес, особенно адреса сайтов, часто очень длинные. И тут встает вопрос: как их переносить?
Существуют ли какие-то правила переноса интернет-адресов и адресов электронной почты? Можно ли просто переносить их на новую строку или нужно ставить какой-то знак? Как лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spravka.gramota.ru
К сожалению, мы ничего не знаем о таких правилах. Но (по логике) переносы вряд ли допустимы, знак переноса может исказить ссылку. Можно договориться и на месте переноса ставить какой-нибудь знак (которого нет в имени ссылки).

От себя могу добавить, что лучше переносить весь адрес целиком, без каких-либо дроблений. Это поможет избежать путаницы.